# Adding meta tab for CSP issues in lighting web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, csp

I am using some MDN to load styles and fonts from google but in it is throwing error in the console.

> lwc_engine.js:6242 Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-inline' *.visualforce.com https://computing-computing-8460-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

How will I include the MDN styles and fonts into lightning web component.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no CSP rule configured in the CSP Trusted Sites

This is an overview of CSP:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5

This shows the steps of how to add a new remote site:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&type=5